# The epochs of my GRU models are showing up multiple times and model training suddenly decreased significantly

Tags: python, keras, lstm, tensorflow2.0, gated-recurrent-unit

I am training neural networks for my thesis and the output behaviour of my notebook has significantly changed. It seems like for the GRU model the epoch output is getting printed more than double. The training time of my LSTM model also significantly increased all of the sudden with at least 140 ms per step compared to 80 ms seconds per epoch it used to be. I am not sure whetehr it is related though. For clarity this is what is happening in my output, I would say it is printing this at least 100 times. Also when I train my LSTM model this does not happen. I am not sure whether anyone has every seen something similar before?

```
`Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...
126/126 - 4s - loss: 0.0525 - val_loss: 0.0261 - 4s/epoch - 34ms/step
Epoch 2/100
126/126 - 1s - loss: 0.0098 - val_loss: 0.0233 - 942ms/epoch - 7ms/step
Epoch 3/100
126/126 - 1s - loss: 0.0091 - val_loss: 0.0207 - 945ms/epoch - 7ms/step
Epoch 4/100
126/126 - 1s - loss: 0.0083 - val_loss: 0.0186 - 944ms/epoch - 7ms/step
Epoch 5/100
126/126 - 1s - loss: 0.0079 - val_loss: 0.0174 - 968ms/epoch - 8ms/step
Epoch 6/100
126/126 - 1s - loss: 0.0076 - val_loss: 0.0160 - 952ms/epoch - 8ms/step
Epoch 7/100
126/126 - 1s - loss: 0.0074 - val_loss: 0.0153 - 920ms/epoch - 7ms/step
Epoch 8/100
126/126 - 1s - loss: 0.0071 - val_loss: 0.0148 - 870ms/epoch - 7ms/step
Epoch 9/100
126/126 - 1s - loss: 0.0069 - val_loss: 0.0142 - 882ms/epoch - 7ms/step
Epoch 10/100
126/126 - 1s - loss: 0.0067 - val_loss: 0.0140 - 912ms/epoch - 7ms/step
Epoch 11/100
126/126 - 1s - loss: 0.0064 - val_loss: 0.0139 - 910ms/epoch - 7ms/step
Epoch 12/100
126/126 - 1s - loss: 0.0063 - val_loss: 0.0135 - 910ms/epoch - 7ms/step
Epoch 13/100
126/126 - 1s - loss: 0.0062 - val_loss: 0.0146 - 917ms/epoch - 7ms/step
...
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 23ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 22ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 24ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 29ms/step
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...
126/126 - 4s - loss: 0.0525 - val_loss: 0.0261 - 4s/epoch - 34ms/step
Epoch 2/100
126/126 - 1s - loss: 0.0098 - val_loss: 0.0233 - 942ms/epoch - 7ms/step
Epoch 3/100
126/126 - 1s - loss: 0.0091 - val_loss: 0.0207 - 945ms/epoch - 7ms/step
Epoch 4/100
126/126 - 1s - loss: 0.0083 - val_loss: 0.0186 - 944ms/epoch - 7ms/step
Epoch 5/100
126/126 - 1s - loss: 0.0079 - val_loss: 0.0174 - 968ms/epoch - 8ms/step
Epoch 6/100
126/126 - 1s - loss: 0.0076 - val_loss: 0.0160 - 952ms/epoch - 8ms/step
Epoch 7/100
126/126 - 1s - loss: 0.0074 - val_loss: 0.0153 - 920ms/epoch - 7ms/step
Epoch 8/100
126/126 - 1s - loss: 0.0071 - val_loss: 0.0148 - 870ms/epoch - 7ms/step
Epoch 9/100
126/126 - 1s - loss: 0.0069 - val_loss: 0.0142 - 882ms/epoch - 7ms/step
Epoch 10/100
126/126 - 1s - loss: 0.0067 - val_loss: 0.0140 - 912ms/epoch - 7ms/step
Epoch 11/100
126/126 - 1s - loss: 0.0064 - val_loss: 0.0139 - 910ms/epoch - 7ms/step
Epoch 12/100
126/126 - 1s - loss: 0.0063 - val_loss: 0.0135 - 910ms/epoch - 7ms/step
Epoch 13/100
```

I fully reinstalled VScode, I already created a new python environment.